# Support for both user-inputed arguments and file output arguments in C

Tags: c, file, arguments, args

Say I have a program that accepts command-line arguments.

```
$ ./foo a b c
```

I can use args[i] to retrieve the values of each arguments. However, I can't pass the content of a file as argument.

```
$ ./foo < file
```

where file would be something like

```
a
b
c
```

Conversely, I can read the arguments from the file if I use

```
while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
```

but then reading arguments like the first method does not work unless I use `$(< ...)` (which I would rather not), it seems like it never reaches EOF.

How can I handle both methods?

Thank you!

Comment: With `./foo < file` the `argc` value will be 1. That tells you that there aren't any command line arguments, so the code should proceed to read from `stdin`. When you use `./foo a b c` the `argc` value will be 4, so the code can extract the arguments from `argv`.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement - if the arguments are on the command line - are those list of files (and each has need to be read), or are those list of values. In other words, are you trying to implement something like `cat` (which without argument will process stdin) ?

Comment: @dash-o They are values. What @user3386109 said is fine but it fails if I add flags to the program such as `./foo -s param_s < file_with_values` since `argc` value is no longer 1. I'm trying to feed my program either user-inputed arguments to be treated as values or a file of the values that is redirected to stdin.

Comment: @J.Doe If the program takes command line options, you can process the options with the POSIX `getopt` function (or parse the options yourself). Then apply the logic to whatever arguments are left.